# Android Brightness refresh not working

Tags: android

My screen is not refreshing after I set new brightness. I googled it, tried few things, what am I doing wrong ?

```
public class  Brightness  extends  Activity { 

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.brightness); 
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    Button low = (Button)findViewById(R.id.low);

     low.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener() 
     {
            public void   onClick(View arg0)
            {
                setUp(100);

    }});
     Button medium = (Button)findViewById(R.id.medium);
     medium.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener()
     {
            public void   onClick(View arg0)
            {
                setUp(200);

    }});
     Button high = (Button)findViewById(R.id.high);
     high.setOnClickListener( new Button.OnClickListener()
     {
            public void   onClick(View arg0)
            {
                setUp(255);

    }});         
}
    public void setUp(int SysBackLightValue)
    {
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,  SysBackLightValue);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
        layoutParams.screenBrightness = SysBackLightValue;
        getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And this is the activity from where it's calling Brightness.java

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 10)
    {
        Log.i("login", "In ActivityRedult My screen brightness is ");
        try 
        {
            oldBrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
            layoutParams.screenBrightness = oldBrightness;
            getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
                    } 
        catch (SettingNotFoundException e1) 
        {
            Log.i("login", "CATCH My screen brightness is " + e1.toString());
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't remember the reason for doing this, but there are two ways to set the brightness, and they are used at different times (or possibly supported by different api's)

Here is a portion of my code that I use for my app Super Dimmer on the market (refactored for your case). Try using this code instead:

```
oldBrightness = Settings.System.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
Settings.System.putInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, oldBrightness);    
WindowManager.LayoutParams llayoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = (float) (oldBrightness/ 255.0);
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

I think the difference was that you are missing the putInt(). Also, is your screen always full brightness? I could be wrong, but in my app, I am dividing by 255 when I set the layoutParams attribute, and it works like a charm.

Comment: You are a genius! Didvided by 255 worked for me too!! Thanks.